# How to use Font Awesome 3.2.1 icons on version 4.5.0?

Tags: html, icons, bower, font-awesome

I installed in my project the latest version of Font Awesome using `bower`.
Now i'm trying to use some icons like this http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/3.2.1/icon/check-empty that are from version 3.2.1, but it doesn't show any icon.

I tried `<i class="icon-check-empty"></i>` and also `<i class="fa icon-check-empty"></i>` or `<i class="fa fa-icon-check-empty"></i>`, but nothing is displayed.

Do you know any work around to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Paste the following code into the `<head>` section of your site's HTML.

```
 <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And [here](https://jsfiddle.net/RenjithVR4/c5nkyx72/5/) you can see how it is working.

**UPDATE::**

> Want to use Font Awesome by itself without Bootstrap? Just don't
>   include the first line.